# How to unit test ASRs On Pivotal CRM

Tags: unit-testing, pivotal-crm

I am using Pivotal CRM and I do not find easy ways  to code unit test for its ASRs for this software. Do you have any experience programming test for this software?

Edit: I have thought a simple but not perfect way of testing. But I am willing to give the Bounty to anybody who gives the minimun insight.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  I would inject stubs or mocks on the implemented methods to set up the test.  So if I implement the IRFormScript interface like below.  I could use a stub that implements the IRForm interface to setup expectations on the form object that gets injected into my methods.  Some of these arguments are just strings too, so those are easy.  You would also have to stub out any other interfaces to Pivotal in order to test your functionality without actually hitting the real system.(IRSystem7, DataAccess, etc.)  Hope this helps!  [Brandon Joyce](http://blog.sonerdy.com)

```
public class TDD : Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRFormScript
{        
    public object AddFormData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, object Recordsets, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DeleteFormData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, object RecordId, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Execute(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, string MethodName, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object LoadFormData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, object RecordId, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object NewFormData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void NewSecondaryData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, object SecondaryName, ref object ParameterList, ref Pivotal.Interop.ADODBLib.Recordset Recordset)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SaveFormData(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.IRForm pForm, object Recordsets, ref object ParameterList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetSystem(Pivotal.Interop.RDALib.RSystem pSystem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hi Brandom, Thanks a lot. I am having problems accepting your answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637822/is-there-a-bug-keeps-me-from-accepting-an-answer-from-an-expired-bounty)

Anyway I will need to try. But I feel that I missing somethig of the big picture and I am new to testing.

Comment: Mocking or stubbing out all this stuff may seem like some work, but it's pretty easy with a mocking framework like Rhino Mocks.  It's really about being able to test this thing in isolation.  It's worth the effort.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only possible answer I find is to move the logic to other clases than would be called by the ASR. This way you can unit test the classes. ASR become more complicated and would only be tested as part of integration test.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think twice about programming anything into Pivotal CRM. CDC is just not hip to modern programming techniques. Treat it as a "tweak only if absolutely necessary" platform, and you will do well.

I don't mean to be harsh, but if you are posting questions about Pivotal CRM on stackoverflow.com, then you are probably using Pivotal CRM wrong.

I say this because I know first hand the pain that comes from using it wrong. I worked with it for 6 years.

Comment: I agree it's a bit of a pain in the behind, but you could probably say this about a lot of "Enterprisey" software.  The point is that you do have a way here to test the code you're putting in your implementation by using stubbing/mocking techniques.  And my advice would be to definitely do it!